# Reverse for [VIEW] with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django, mezzanine

I get the error `NoReverseMatch at /`. I need to understand what caused this and how to resolve this issue.

```
Reverse for 'sites' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

This is my setup with Mezzanine:

**project_name/app/templates/index.html:**

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="{% url "sites" %}">{% trans "Sites" %} <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="{% url "sites" %}">{% trans "All Sites" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "sites_new" %}">{% trans "New Sites" %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url "latest_entries" %}">{% trans "Latest Entries" %}</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
```

**project_name/app/views.py:**

```
def sites(request):
    return render(request, 'lists/sites.html')

def sites_new(request):
    return render(request, 'lists/sites_new.html')

def latest_entries(request):
    latest_entries = BlogPost.objects.all().filter(site_id=1, publish_date__lte=datetime.date.today())[:50]
    context = {'latest_posts': latest_posts}
    return render(request, 'lists/latest_entries.html', context)
```

**project_name/app/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sites/$', views.sites, name='sites'),
    url(r'^sites/new/$', views.sites_new, name='sites_new'),
    url(r'^latest/$', views.latest_entries, name='latest_entries'),
]
```

**project_name/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns += [
    url('^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}, name='home'), 
    url('^', include('mezzanine.urls')),
]
```

Comment: So, where is the "sites" URL defined?

Comment: Did none of the related questions on the right help?

Comment: @Sayse: No, sorry they do not. I have checked all my urls in my template and they have single quotes. They do not have any arguments in the urls.py and so forth...

Comment: *"0 patterns tried"* Does your setting `ROOT_URLCONF = 'project_name.urls'`?